# How to create a custom keyboard-shortcut for renaming files on CentOS?

Tags: centos, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create a keyboard-shortcut for renaming files, like the <kbd>F2</kbd> key in Windows. How can I do that in CentOS 6.4?

Following is the image of the panel for keyboard shortcuts:

[image: keyboard shortcuts panel]

Comment: Have you checked F2? In Ubuntu it works!

Comment: Yes , I checked

Comment: Where exactly do you want this action to occur? When in Nautilus? It already works that way. I use F2 to rename a file's name after selecting it in Nautilus.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut is part of Nautilus, it's not a GNOME keyboard shortcut. For the entire desktop. I think you're trying to solve this problem incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a screenshot of me doing it on Fedora 19 in Nautilus using the <kbd>F2</kbd>.

[image: ss of nautilus dir rename using F2]

I confirmed on CentOS 6.4 & 6.5 and it does exactly the same thing.

Comment: I want to create one,my one is not working!

Comment: Great, `F2` works for me (Debian). Where do I find all the shortcuts for Nautilus / Gnome "Files"?

Comment: @0__ - https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet